# EF :Why Updating Database the number type column become 0?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I am using ef and reflection to implement updating specified column.
the string column can exexute correct,the number type column has changed when I update 1 time, the 2nd times I found it  has become 0;

```
public void UpdateSpecified(T entity)
    {
        var props = entity.GetType().GetProperties();
        foreach (var prop in props)
        {
            if (prop.PropertyType.IsPrimitive || prop.PropertyType == typeof(string))
            {
                string propValue = prop.GetValue(entity, null) != null ? prop.GetValue(entity, null).ToString() : string.Empty;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(propValue))
                {
                    DataContext.Entry<T>(entity).Property(prop.Name).IsModified = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    DataContext.Entry<T>(entity).Property(prop.Name).IsModified = false;
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

service Layer Code:

```
    g.Id = good.Id;
    g.GoodsQuantity = good.GoodsQuantity - 1;
    goodsRepo.Attach(g);
    goodsRepo.UpdateSpecified(g);
    _repositoryFactory.Commit();
```

Comment: Are you re fetching from the db before the second update?

Comment: hi ,I have solved it ,see my answer below

Answer (score -1):

I have Solved it.
first you have to define your number type model to **Nullable** Type

```
    public float? GoodPrice { get; set; }

    public float? GoodScore { get; set; }

    public int? GoodsQuantity { get; set; }
```

Second:you should change your ef mapping class like this:

```
    this.Property(x => x.GoodsQuantity).IsRequired();
    this.Property(x => x.GoodPrice).IsRequired();
    this.Property(x => x.GoodScore).IsRequired();
```

Third: you should change your code like this:

```
  public void UpdateSpecified(T entity)
    {
        var props = entity.GetType().GetProperties();
        foreach (var prop in props)
        {
            if (prop.PropertyType.IsPrimitive || prop.PropertyType == typeof(string)
                ||(prop.PropertyType.IsGenericType&& prop.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition()==typeof(Nullable<>)))
            {
                string propValue = prop.GetValue(entity, null) != null ? prop.GetValue(entity, null).ToString() : string.Empty;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(propValue))
                {
                    DataContext.Entry<T>(entity).Property(prop.Name).IsModified = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    DataContext.Entry<T>(entity).Property(prop.Name).IsModified = false;
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

at last ,it can change it correctly.xd

Comment: if it is required, why did you specify a nullable type?